# How to programmatically find if the object type is of Google Protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, isinstance

I have a case where I receive objects from another module. The object type can be JSON String, dict or of Google Protobuf. I can use isinstance in python to determine whether it is JSON String or dict, but finding it difficult to use `isinstance` to check if it is `protobuf`. I am not even sure if `isinstance` can be used for non-primitive types like Google Protobuf.

So, Is there a way to check the given object is of Google Protobuf type in Python?

Comment: If the types can be only one of three, why not check for the first two and assume it’s Protobuf in the associated `else`?

Comment: One approach (not sure if best in this case) is to just try deserializing the value and wrapping it with `try ... except` to catch the error if it isn't valid Protobuf.

Comment: `I am not even sure if isinstance can be used for non primitive types like Google Protobuf.` ... can you think of a way to find out?

Comment: `isinstance()` will work on non-primitive types.

Comment: @esqew I don’t want assume like that and instead want to check specifically and conclude.                      

Danielle, martineau Do you guys what type to pass for Protobuf ?? I couldn’t figure this out either from documentation or from Google/StackOverflow

Comment: user2896235: The documentation for [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) says that the *`classinfo`*  argument can be a tuple of type objects which implies you can check for multiple types in one call to it. As far as @Danielle's comment goes, you could just try it on a `protobuf` and see if it works.

Comment: you can try creating a dummy ```protobuf``` variable with name ```dummy``` and then compare ```type(your_var)==type(dummy)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you receiving Protobuf objects or serialized (binary) strings?

If you're receiving objects then these *should* be subclasses of [Message](https://googleapis.dev/python/protobuf/latest/google/protobuf/message.html#google.protobuf.message.Message) and [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) using your `object` for `Message` should be true for protobufs.

If your incoming object is `o` and:

```py
assert isinstance(json.loads(o), dict)
assert isinstance(o, dict)

from google.protobuf.message import Message
assert isinstance(o, Message)
assert issubclass(o, Message)
```

Even though it's more effort to test for each type (JSON, dict, proto), I think it would be better to confirm the object's type before proceeding.

You can short-circuit the tests by only testing until you find a match but you want to avoid some 4th type being added in the future and your code assuming that anything that's not JSON or dict is a proto.

Comment: Passing Message, message, protobuf, proto as type to isinstance didn't work. All the case got a response as name 'x' is not defined. x is Message, message or protobuf etc.

Comment: If your incoming object is `o` and your `json.loads(o)` and `isinstance(o, dict)` then you should be able to `from google.protobuf.message import Message` and `isinstance(o, Message)` and `issubclass(o, Message)`

Comment: Excellent. This works. May be you should update your answer with this information.

Comment: @DazWilkin how we can use isinstance with protobuf binary message?

Comment: Then deserialize it first (`ParseFromString`). Please don't ask new questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

`isinstance` can be used for any type.  And, for what it's worth, types can be *treated like* classes. (Someone with more knowledge, please edit this to be more precise.)

For instance, you can do the following:

```py
class mytype(str):
   pass

>>> tmp = mytype("this")
>>> tmp
'this'
>>> type(tmp)
<class '__main__.mytype'>
>>> isinstance(tmp, str)
True
>>> isinstance(mytype, type)
True
```

---

But to your main question:

- I would *suggest* that you probably want to test for the protobuf type itself.

For instance, if your protobuf is:

`myperson.proto`

```
syntax = "proto3";
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  string address = 2;
  int32 age = 3;
}
```

then you would do something like:

```py
>>> from myperson_pb2 import Person
>>> from google.protobuf.message import Message
>>> person = Person(name="me", address="right here", age=2)
>>> isinstance(person, Person)
True
>>> isinstance(person, Message)
True
```

So, while you can see both are `True` (because `Person` inherits from `Message`), I would argue that it is better to check for the `Person` object itself, if you know that.

There are two reasons I would recommend this:

1. Knowing that something is of the `Person` type provides far more information, enough information that you can now fully parse it as needed.
2. `Message` is not the only type of protobuf type. There are also `RepeatedCompositeContainer` and `RepeatedScalarContainer` to capture array-like entries, and several others, I'm sure. So, if you only test for `Message`, you may miss a protocol buffer *object* when you're trying to make a generic test.

---

Finally, it might help to understand what your class inheritance looks like. You can easily do that by performing `help` on your object:

```py
>>> help(person)
Help on Person in module myperson_pb2 object:

class Person(google._upb._message.Message, google.protobuf.message.Message)
 |  Method resolution order:
 |      Person
 |      google._upb._message.Message
 |      google.protobuf.message.Message
 |      builtins.object
 |  
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  CustomEntry = <class '__main__.myperson_pb2.CustomEntry...
 |  
 |  DESCRIPTOR = <google._upb._message.Descriptor object>
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Methods inherited from google._upb._message.Message:
.
.
.
```

So you can see that your protobuf object inherits from `google._upb._message.Message`, which inherits from `google.protobuf.message.Message`.